# Is it possible to search among content of documents?

Tags: search, document-management

I was wondering if it is possible to search among content of documents

- possibly of various types: pdf, djvu,
  html, text file, programming code
  script, ...
- possibly under various directories
  under each the documents are  mixed
  together and possibly with other
  nondocument files?

Is grep capable of doing these kinds of thing?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3):

I use Recoll. It's in the repositories. It also searches pdf-metadata. You can choose, which folders are indexed. It's very fast.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install recoll
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Have a look at [FindingFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles) in the community documentation for Ubuntu. The one I used for a while was [Tracker](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaTracker) which is able to index most document types and, due to keeping an index updated in the background, was amazingly fast when searching.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a command on the files returned by the find command.
For example with the following command I list all the files starting from the current directory and on each I run the grep command to search for the string 'getUri'

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec grep --color 'getURI' {} +
```

This works perfectly on my Ubuntu 12.04

Anyway, I do not think that grep command is able to search within binary documents such as PDF.
 
Also using the command above on a large directory tree could be very burdensome in terms of computational time.
Another aspect to consider is that you can not search for a string in a raster PDF, in suck kind of scenario a document management system as [LogicalDoc](http://www.logicaldoc.com) could help.